# Preciso que me ajudem com esta questão em C

Tags: c

Tenho uma dúvida relativamente ao meu código. Acho que a minha lógica está correta, no entanto, o troco em cédulas de 1,00R$ não está a funcionar de forma correta. Alguma sugestão?

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {

    int valor_produto = 0, valor_pagamento = 0, troco = 0;
    scanf("%d", &valor_produto);
    scanf("%d", &valor_pagamento);
    troco = valor_pagamento - valor_produto;
    if (valor_pagamento  > valor_produto ){
        printf("100: %d\n", troco / 100);
        printf("50: %d\n", troco % 100 / 50);
        printf("20: %d\n", troco % 50 / 20 );
        printf("10: %d\n", troco % 20 / 10);
        printf("5: %d\n", troco % 10 / 5);
        printf("2: %d\n", troco % 5 / 2);
        printf("1: %d\n", troco / 2 );
    }
    else printf("O valor pago é insuficiente, faltam %d R$",troco * -1);

    return 1;



    }
```

Comment: Porque pela sua lógica você sempre pega primeiro as maiores notas com que possa formar o valor desejado.

Comment: Mas estar correta?

Comment: Não. No lugar de sempre partir do valor inicial de troco a cada cálculo mantenha em troco apenas o resto da divisão com o valor da nota anterior.

Comment: entao seria de forma?                                                                               
   printf("100: %d\n", troco / 100);
    printf("50: %d\n", troco % 100 / 50);
    printf("20: %d\n", troco % 100 % 50 / 20 );
    printf("10: %d\n", troco % 100 %50 %20 / 10);
    printf("5: %d\n", troco % 100 % 50 % 20 % 10 / 5);
    printf("2: %d\n", troco % 100 % 50 % 20 % 10 % 5 / 2);
    printf("1: %d\n", troco %100 % 50 % 20 % 10 % 5 % 2 / 1 );
}

Comment: Pode ser. Note que não tem muito sentido a divisão por 1 no último printf. Talvez você não tenha estudado vetores mas seu uso certamente simplificará bastante seu programa.

Answer (score 0):

A ideia dessa questão é lembrar que, se voce tem, por exemplo, 155 reais, voce sabe que:

- A quantidade de notas de cem vai ser igual a 155/100, lembrando que estamos considerando a divisão inteira. Ou seja, temos uma nota de cem, e o resto é 55. Logo teríamos que trabalhar com 55 reais.

Resumindo, a ideia principal pra resolução do problema é saber sempre atualizar o valor do troco, ou seja:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

int valor_produto = 0, valor_pagamento = 0, troco = 0;
scanf("%d", &valor_produto);
scanf("%d", &valor_pagamento);
troco = valor_pagamento - valor_produto;
if (valor_pagamento  > valor_produto ){
    printf("100: %d\n", troco / 100);
    troco = troco%100;
    printf("50: %d\n", troco / 50) ;
    troco= troco %50;
    printf("20: %d\n", troco / 20) ;
    troco = troco %20;
    printf("10: %d\n", troco / 10) ;
    troco = troco %10;
    printf("5: %d\n", troco / 5) ;
    troco = troco%5;
    printf("2: %d\n", troco / 2);
    printf("1: %d\n", troco%2   );
}
else printf("O valor pago é insuficiente, faltam %d R$",troco * -1);

return 1;
}
```

A variavel troco sempre vai receber o resto da ultima divisão.